# Javascript push JSON to Array (Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts

I have this empty array:

```
var seriesGraficos =[];
```

and this already made vars:

```
var dataEnergiaContratadaA = [1458, 1332, 777];
var dataDemandaA = [18, 13, 77];
var nameEnergiaContratadaA = "Energy";
var nameDemandaA = "Demand";
```

and I need to fill the array like this way (I need the seriesGraficos exactly like this, it's the series array of Highcharts):

```
seriesGraficos = [{
        name: nameEnergiaContratadaA,
        data: dataEnergiaContratadaA
        }, {
        name: nameDemandaA ,
        data: dataDemandaA
        }];
```

I was trying something like:

```
seriesGraficos.push(
{"name": nameEnergiaContratadaA,"data": dataEnergiaContratadaA},
{"name": nameDemandaA,"data": dataDemandaA}
);
```

But I can't get it. Any help?

Comment: The above example seems to work as it is. It produces the required array. https://plnkr.co/edit/Y7FaTJlLM3h04CuKwATo?p=preview

Comment: @RahulSharma `Array.prototype.push` supports multiple elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Hm, yes, don't know why but I tried manye times and didn't worked, results like a loop of objects, but now it works... (I'm using React, Symfony, Node.js, webpack, etc, maybe was a cache problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in ES6 with spread operator :

```js
seriesGraficos = [];
seriesGraficos.push(...[
{"name": 'nameEnergiaContratada',"data": 'dataEnergiaContratadaA'},
{"name": 'nameDemandaA',"data": 'dataDemandaA'}
]);

console.log(seriesGraficos);
```

Comment: This literally produces the exact same array as the original snippet, doesn't it?

Comment: Hm, I don't know why, but this one works, except that I have the value of the vars, not the 'nameDemandaA¡ for example. Like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZJ09Fyr4xNvQuYxthgCu?p=preview

Comment: I didn't copied it for simplicity. This works, but as peopple say in comments you should use push that accepts multiple elements.